# Winrt Dependency Property Visual Studio XAML error.

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

This is my Dependency property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonTapSoundProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ButtonTapSound", typeof (Uri), typeof (ButtonDependencyObject), new PropertyMetadata(default(Uri), UriChanged));
```

I then use it like this:

```
<Button buttonDependencyObject:ButtonDependencyObject.ButtonTapSound="{Binding ElementName=TapSound}" ... />
```

This works perfectly at design time and run time.

However if I define it inside a control template like this:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Name="TapSound" TargetType="Button">
      <Button buttonDependencyObject:ButtonDependencyObject.ButtonTapSound="{Binding ElementName=TapSound}" ...  />
 </ControlTemplate>
```

It works at runtime but not in the Visual Studio designer

Comment: Just a question: Why are you even placing another button in Button's ControlTemplate?

Comment: Why do you care it doesn't work in the designer?

Comment: @lokusking it happens inside any control template.

Comment: @MichaelThePotato because I do. It's annoying.

Comment: What happens exactly? do you expect the sound to be played? how do you trigger it in design time? are you getting an error in the designer?

Comment: Yes I expect a sound to play... and it does play. It just doesn't play when it is inside a control template. The designer displays the following error message: 

The text associated with this error code could not be found. Failed to assign to property ButtonTapSound.

Comment: It might help if you could provide some more details of your `ButtonTapSoundProperty`-Class, so we can try to reproduce it. Everything else may lead to various or no results

Answer (score 2):

Due to the lack of further source code I just can refer to the implemenation guidelines of msdn about [dependency properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358(v=vs.110).aspx).

Create a seperate class for your sound button which derives from `Button` e.g "SoundButton" and register your property with getter and setter.

```
class SoundButton : Button
{
    public Uri ButtonTapSound
    {
        get { return (Uri)GetValue(ButtonTapSoundProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ButtonTapSoundProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonTapSoundProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonTapSound", typeof(Uri), typeof(SoundButton), new PropertyMetadata(default(Uri), new PropertyChangedCallback(OnUriChanged)));

    private static void OnUriChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       //Your code
    }
}
```

Then you can use it in your code as it is, without registering the dependecy property in xaml:

```
 <local:SoundButton ButtonTapSound="{Binding ElementName=TapSound}"></local:SoundButton>
```

This is may not be done in your style, but should solve the designer issues.